# Tag editor badge description incomplete

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-wiki, edit-badges

The description simply reads:

> First Tag Wiki Edit.

It needs to be made clear that you only get this for editing the **body** of a wiki entry.

You don't get it for creating the tag wiki or editing the excerpt.

Comment: I think I would prefer to fix the badge to it goes out editing excerpts as well and creating wikis.

Comment: @waffles - that works for me too! (sorry only just seen this comment)

Comment: @waffles: I guess someone just had to [ask for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72425/change-the-tag-editor-badge-for-a-tag-creator-badge)

Comment: Tag Wiki excerpt = Edit, so why is it 2nd class and not recognized? Badge's broken IMHO. The excerpt is also more prominent than the body itself, so the priority seems wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed, we now provide the tag editor badge to all users who either create or edit a tag wiki *or* a tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: Was this change reverted?  We have people who have been creating tags on [japanese](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/) for the past few days but nobody has earned the badge yet.  Does it not work if your edit has to be approved?

Comment: Yesterday I edited a tag wiki (edit approved) but I earned no badge!

Comment: doesn't seem to work, see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100877/should-i-have-gotten-the-tag-editor-badge).

Comment: It looks like it's still not working. I've edited many tag wikis today and got no badge :(

Comment: @Laurent fixed, see [this meta post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/936/tag-editor-badge-bug-detected/937#937).