# There's a badge for editing a tag wiki entry but not one for creating a tag wiki entry?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badge-request, tag-wiki, edit-badges

Shouldn't there be a badge for creating a tag wiki entry?

And should it be retroactive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tag editor badge description incomplete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63447/tag-editor-badge-description-incomplete)

Comment: @ChrisF Possible but a little different.  Let's leave it up the pole and see who salutes.

Comment: +1. Because I would get this badge.

Comment: There's no way this question is a duplicate of 63447. (It *is* Friday, but still...)

Answer (score 3):

Tag editor badge was kind of weird, you now get it for either creating or editing

Answer (score 1):

That behavior seems kind of weird to me too, but I'm not sure it's worth "fixing." As time goes by, more and more tags will already have wikis, so it will be harder and harder for anyone to actually get new "created a tag wiki" badges (though, admittedly, Taxonomist suffers from the same issue).

Also, anyone who's planning on creating a wiki could always just make a small edit <strike>immediately</strike> a little more than five minutes after posting the initial version to get the badge (thanks for pointing that detail out, @ChrisF!). So if you care that much, the badge is open to you.

Comment: Not "immediately" but after 5 minutes so that it counts as a separate edit and doesn't get rolled into the initial creation.

Comment: That's the point. Editing a tag wiki, most can do that. But actually creating one, well, that's a bit more special, might deserve notice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there should be a separate badge, but I don't see why you shouldn't get the *Tag Editor*  badge for creating a tag wiki.

Answer (score 0):

If there was one it would just be an incentive for people to create more unnecessary tags, which we seem to have plenty of already.