# Tag Editor Not Working?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-wiki, edit-badges

I created a tag wiki for a tag that was missing one. I also added a small bit of content to an existing tag. I did not get the badge. I saw a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63447/tag-editor-badge-description-incomplete) stating that creating a wiki was now included in the badge calculation. Regardless I have also edited it and it seems to be approved. Any new news on this?

Comment: The same on other SE sites.

Comment: Could you link the site (and associated tag wiki) where you should have the badge?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execution-plan

Comment: a) these things don't get applied right away. b) You should have gotten it.

Comment: I have received another badge between then and now, so it should have picked up then I assume. Still no badge.

Comment: @Grace Note Nobody at [japanese.se] has this badge even though our tag wikis have descriptions (in my case, I suggested the excerpt and description for [translations](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info)).  I wonder if it is bugged if the tag was edited via a suggested edit (since being a new site, none of us had the reputation to edit without going through the queue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confirmed, a few weeks ago I refactored the Posts table to allow for a whole bunch of new PostTypeIds.

TagWiki and TagWikiExcerpt are now PostTypeId 5 and 4. The badge checks for PostTypeId 3.

I am committing a fix to the badge today.

Comment: Fix seems to work, at least for me.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a "me too" answer but I can confirm that the tag editor badge appears to be broken. I recently (three or four days ago) edited my first tag ("cryptography") both on stackoverflow and security.stackexchange. On SO, I do not have trusted user privileges yet, so this went through peer approval, who did approve (I got the +2 rep changes); on SE I have the trusted user privileges, so no peer approval. Right now, no tag editor badge for me, neither on SO or security.SE.