# Not receiving badge after editing a tag

Tags: support, bug, tags, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag Editor Not Working?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94381/tag-editor-not-working)

I just discovered the [fancy](http://www.fancy-lang.org/) programming language yesterday and I found out that it did not contain a tag wiki, so I proposed one (which I edited again because I missed somethings) as I do not have 20000 reputation on StackOverflow to edit it.

Eventhough it got accepted and I got some reputation for it, I did not get the **[Tag editor]** badge.

Is this intentional or some kind of bug?

Comment: Maybe because you were the first it's not considered editing, but adding?

Comment: Yes but I got points for editing not creating the tags. The creation of the tags was made by someone else. Anyhow I edited the tag-wiki twice, as I missed something the first time, and both got approved.

Comment: Good points - no idea then..

Comment: See also [this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94381/tag-editor-not-working).