# Has the tag editor badge requirements changed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edit-badges

I have created new tag wiki (and its excerpt) [back in June 5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10892428/revisions) and kind of forgot about it.

Today I suddenly noticed I [was awarded the Tag Editor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/254/tag-editor?userid=447356) for that wiki although I created, not edited, it.

I checked the [List of all badges and full description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) which clearly says in the Tag Editor section:

> You need to edit an existing tag wiki; creating a new one does not count

While I really don't mind extra badge, I also wonder if this is by design meaning change of rules, or just a local/temporary bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The badge now includes initial edits to the tag wiki and exceprts.  This was an intentional change that didn't quite work previously (one part of the query was fixed, one was not)...it now *does* work as part of my changing it a few days ago.

I changed the badge so it stopped timing out and returned rather fast, because we typically prefer that over timeouts...but *fixing* it while I was in there seemed like a good idea too :)

Comment: Cheers, but wasn't it a bug i.e. status-completed?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - not in the context of *this* question :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that is just outdated. That entire badge description is just confusing, as it doesn't mention suggested edits (still says you *have to have* 20,000 reputation) and rambles on about old rules.

Anyways, here's the [relevant update from waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80164) in Feb 2011:

> Fixed, we now provide the tag editor badge to all users who either create or edit a tag wiki *or* a tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: OK, so why it took 3 months for the badge to arrive?

Comment: Perhaps a bug that was recently fixed? You *should* have the badge though. :)

Comment: Looks like bug indeed, [here is another user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/358970/marcind?tab=activity&sort=badges) who got it just now for tag wiki he created [back in February](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9332028/1)..